# Azure sql database grant select on certain tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

I have created a user in a Azure sql database in SSMS. Now trying to give select permission to certain tables in a db to this user. The security control options seems quite different than on premise sql server. How can I do these on a Azure db?

I have tried this on a on premise sql server and it works fine. But got error when run these on the azure sql db.

```
    USE [master]
    GO
    CREATE LOGIN [jnj_user] WITH PASSWORD=N'P2ssw0rd123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[CRM], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
    GO
    USE [CRM]
    GO
    CREATE USER [jnj_user] FOR LOGIN [jnj_user]
    GO
```

error:

```
    Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
    Keyword or statement option 'default_database' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
    Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
    USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```

also this does not work on Azure db either:

```
    GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[JJVCEtrialOB] TO  jnj_user
```

error:

```
    Cannot find the user 'jnj_user', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure the login is added on all the levels

```
---- ON SERVER LEVEL
CREATE LOGIN TestUser
    WITH PASSWORD = 'ThisIsAStrongPassword!' 
GO

---- ON Master Level
CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo


---- ON SQL DB LEVEL
CREATE USER TestUser
    FOR LOGIN TestUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO

GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.Sales TO TestUser;
GO
```

You need to add the `login` on server level under the master context

then add a user to the `master` db under `master` context

and then add the user to the `sqldb` and grant its rights

**EDIT** You cannot use the use statement, so you will have to manually switch context in SSMS

Answer (score 2):

With Azure SQL Database, accounts in the master database are needed only for administrative accounts that need access to all databases of the logical server.

For non-admin users, create a user account in the database for non-admin users so that the user is authenticated at the database level and then grant the needed permissions. See [Azure SQL logins and users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

```
CREATE USER [jnj_user] WITH PASSWORD='<your-complex-password>';
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.Sales TO jnj_user;
```